# Duplicate Row - Interactive Grid - Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there any way I can use the duplicate row option in interactive grid and pass parameter that I want eg. 10 duplicate rows of the selected row with different IDs?

I'm using Apex 20.1

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you would have to program it yourself. As a start the command to duplicate the current selected record is:

```
apex.region("regionStaticID").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("duplicate-record")
```

You can ofcourse modify that to a process that repeats the command x times and modify the ID.

More detailed information about this subject can be found at John Snyders [blogs about the Interactive Grid](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/02/20/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-3/). They are not easy, but incredibly usefull.

Comment: Upvote for the hack APEX Interactive Grid blogs, that stuff is gold.

https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet is a good resource also, links to the hack APEX blogs, along with a ton of other stuff. Really usefull when you are starting out, and as a reference later on

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and additional documentation @TineO. Together, these blogs are tha bomb and should actually be bundled in a book, owned by every single APEX developer :)